# OpenGL ES 2.0 GLSL rendering multiple sprites with unique textures

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsl

I am creating a very simple Android game which has various sprites which use different texture atlases. The texture atlases are stored as different image files. What is the most efficient way to use OpenGL ES 2.0 to render these different textures to different sprites?

Currently, I am reloading each sprite texture every time I render that sprite to the game screen, which I realize is **not effective at all**. I would like to be able to upload the texture atlases **once** to the GPU and then use the cached texture in GPU memory to render to the respective sprite vertices.

Below is my vertex and fragment shader GLSL code. Here are my questions:

1. Is there any way to change the shaders to render multiple textures independently to different vertices (ie. rendering different sprites on the screen)?

or

2. Do I have to create multiple OpenGL programs using these shaders (compiling the shaders multiple  with each OpenGL program dedicated to rendering a specific sprite? **(also doesn't seem very efficient)**

Most of the books I've found on OpenGL ES 2.0 have texture shading examples consisting only of shading a single texture. Other examples I've found online demonstrate using multiple overlapping textures. I have yet to find a source which talks about an efficient method for shading different vertices with different textures, so any insight you can give me is greatly appreciated.

Also, how can I update the vertex buffer in GPU memory (ie. the sprite's location on the screen) without having to change the values in Java and then re-write them back to the GPU? Are there any good GLSL functions for this? To avoid similar memory-thrashing between CPU cores and the GPU?

Thanks in advance for any advice you can give-- I'm very new to OpenGL and GLSL.

^_^

**Vertex Shader:**

```
precision highp float;
uniform mat4 u_orthMatrix;
attribute vec4 a_position;
attribute vec2 a_inputTextureCoordinate;
varying vec2 v_textureCoordinate;

void main() {
    gl_Position = u_orthMatrix * a_position;
    v_textureCoordinate = a_inputTextureCoordinate;
}
```

**Fragment Shader:**

```
precision mediump float;
varying vec2 v_textureCoordinate;
uniform sampler2D u_texture;

void main() {
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_texture, v_textureCoordinate);
}
```

Comment: Have you seen: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/72479/how-can-i-read-from-multiple-textures-in-an-opengl-es-2-shader

Comment: "shading different vertices with different textures" It's not clear what you mean by that. Are you asking about using different textures in the shader, or are you talking about rendering different quads with different textures, one quad per texture? Because I don't know what you issue is with the latter case.

Comment: *`I am reloading each sprite texture every time I render that sprite`* Why ?! If you've read any decent tutorial you're binding your textures not reloading *`What is the most efficient way...`* The most efficient way is to profile your app and optimize depending on the results. *`How can I update the vertex buffer ... without having to change the values in Java`* You cant. If you really have [texture atlases](http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/130940/practical_texture_atlases.php) then its just a matter of scaling and offsetting the UV coordinates either using vertex attributes or uniforms.